# Пропуск в lineplot seaborn для пропущенных данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть график сверху. Хочу попробовать его воспроизвести из этих [данных](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ternikov/hse/gh-pages/hw5/temp_data.csv).

Делаю это так:

```
def month2season(month):
    if 1 <= month <= 2 or month == 12:
        return 'winter'
    elif 3 <= month <= 5:
        return 'spring'
    elif 6 <= month <= 8:
        return 'summer'
    elif 9 <= month <= 11:
        return 'autumn'

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ternikov/hse/gh-pages/hw5/temp_data.csv')
df_grouped = df.groupby(['year', 'month'], as_index=False).mean()
df_grouped['season'] = df_grouped['month'].apply(month2season)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))
for season_data, axes in zip(df_grouped['season'].unique(), ax.reshape(-1)):
    season_data = df_grouped[df_grouped['season'] == season_data]
    sns.lineplot('year', 'temp', data=season_data, ax=axes)
plt.show()
```

Но проблема в том, что `lineplot` соединяет участок с пропущенными значениями таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

После недолгого экспериментирования оказалось, что Seaborn отбрасывает значение бесконечности (`np.inf`), а для значений NaN (np.nan) - соединяет ближайшие значимые (`not NaN`):

```
def month2season(m):
    seasons = ["Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"]
    return np.take(seasons, (m % 12) // 3)

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ternikov/hse/gh-pages/hw5/temp_data.csv")
int_cols = ["year", "month"]
df[int_cols] = df[int_cols].astype(int)

res = pd.DataFrame(list(product(range(1952, 2017), range(1, 13))), columns=int_cols)
res = res.merge(df, how="left")
res["season"] = res["month"].map(month2season)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))

for season, ax in zip(res['season'].unique(), axes.ravel()):
    sns.lineplot('year', 'temp', data=res[res['season'] == season].fillna(np.inf), ax=ax)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он бесконечные значения отбрасывает, получается?